# How to inspect API Gateway deployment contents by ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have made a successful deployment in AWS API Gateway. Later I found out that some of the changes I have made though the console have broken things. I am able to go back to a working deployment using "Deployment history" feature.

How can I see what is inside a specific deployment? More specifically, how can I inspect it in API Gateway console? I am able to "get" a deployment JSON by using CLI `aws apigateway get-deployment --rest-api-id my-api-id-123 --deployment-id abc123` but this yields only meta information about the deployment, not the actual state.

After I deploy the working deployment with "Deployment history", I am not able to see its contents in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I think console does not support such functionality. But in AWS you can get `apiSummary` using `--embed` parameter:

```
aws apigateway get-deployment --rest-api-id my-api-id-123 --deployment-id abc123 --embed apisummary
```

with example output:

```
{
    "id": "u36v7k",
    "createdDate": 1607557728,
    "apiSummary": {
        "/": {
            "GET": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            }
        },
        "/pets": {
            "GET": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",            
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            },
            "OPTIONS": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            },
            "POST": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            }
        },
        "/pets/{petId}": {
            "GET": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            },
            "OPTIONS": {
                "authorizationType": "NONE",
                "apiKeyRequired": false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, this is not really what I am looking for, it merely exposes the list of methods available. I was looking for more detailed information about the API Gateway deployment so I could compare the diff of what went wrong with the deployment.

Comment: @rnli I see. I don't think there is more to it then what you already know and what I wrote in the answer.